# Django template conditional on block substitution

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'd like some content in my Django template to render only if another block in the template is nonempty, like so:

```html
{# base.html #}
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}{% if title_block_is_nonempty %} - {% endif %}My Site Title</title>
```

```html
{# homepage.html #}
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{# This page's title should be "My Site Title". #}
```

```html
{# otherpage.html #}
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Other Page{% endblock %}
{# This page's title should be "Other Page - My Site Title". #}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Without writing any custom template tags - probably not. Nonetheless you can either split the base template into two (with a block and `-` and without), or write  `-` explicitly every time.